# how do I create a function within a function to cycle?

Tags: python, loops

For the following code, it goes through one iteration of the intended algo- my question is how do I loop the below so that I am eventually left with a string with one letter? I know there's probably a lot of ways to do this, but I would like to write a second function that will loop the first one until I am left with just the one letter.

I know the second batch of code below is totally wrong, but can someone amend it? Or come up with something else, but ideally I would like to have the function def ...

```
 row = "BRGGBRG"

 final_sol = ''

 def triangle(row):
     next_row = ''

     while len(next_row) > 1:
         for i in range(len(row)-1):
             if row[i] == 'G' and row[(i + 1)] == 'B':
                 next_row += 'R'
             elif row[i] == 'G' and row[(i + 1)] == 'R':
                 next_row += 'B'
             elif row[i] == 'R' and row[(i + 1)] == 'B':
                 next_row += 'G'
             elif row[i] == 'R' and row[(i + 1)] == 'G':
                 next_row += 'B'
             elif row[i] == 'B' and row[(i + 1)] == 'G':
                 next_row += 'R'
             elif row[i] == 'B' and row[(i + 1)] == 'R':
                 next_row += 'G'
             elif row[i] == 'B' and row[(i + 1)] == 'B':
                 next_row += 'B'
             elif row[i] == 'G' and row[(i + 1)] == 'G':
                 next_row += 'G'
             elif row[i] == 'R' and row[(i + 1)] == 'R':
                 next_row += 'R'

         print(next_row)
         return None

 def loop_the_above(next_row):
          print(next_row)

 loop_the_above((row))
```

Comment: Your `while` loop will never run, since `len(next_row) == 0` when at the beginning.

Comment: You can simplify your `ifs` but comparing the letters at once : `if row[i:i+2] == "GB"`

Comment: The function should return something instead of printing, so the calling loop can test the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `triangle` function should return the next row, not print it.

Then you can assign the result to a variable in a loop when calling it, and test this variable.

```
rgb_map = {'GB': 'R', 'GR': 'B', 'RB': 'G', 'RG': 'B', 'BG': 'R', 'BR': 'G', 'BB': 'B', 'GG': 'G', 'RR': 'R'}

def triangle(row):
    next_row = ""
    for substr in [row[i:i+2] for i in range(len(row)-1)]:
        next_row += rgb_map[substr]        
    return next_row

def loop_the_above(row):
    while len(row) > 1:
        print(row)
        row = triangle(row)

loop_the_above("BRGGBRG")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the condition of your while loop in your first function is incorrect as the while loop doesn't even start. Could you detail what you want to do with the first function?

If you want to go through the letters of `row` you can copy it and delete the letters that have already been treated. These modifications can be found in following code :

```
def triangle(row):
    next_row = ''
    copy_row=row
    
    while len(copy_row) > 1:
        for i in range(len(row)-1):
            if row[i] == 'G' and row[(i + 1)] == 'B':
                next_row += 'R'
    
            elif row[i] == 'G' and row[(i + 1)] == 'R':
                next_row += 'B'
    
            elif row[i] == 'R' and row[(i + 1)] == 'B':
                next_row += 'G'
    
            elif row[i] == 'R' and row[(i + 1)] == 'G':
                next_row += 'B'
    
            elif row[i] == 'B' and row[(i + 1)] == 'G':
                next_row += 'R'
    
            elif row[i] == 'B' and row[(i + 1)] == 'R':
                next_row += 'G'
    
            elif row[i] == 'B' and row[(i + 1)] == 'B':
                next_row += 'B'
    
            elif row[i] == 'G' and row[(i + 1)] == 'G':
                next_row += 'G'
    
            elif row[i] == 'R' and row[(i + 1)] == 'R':
                next_row += 'R'
            copy_row=copy_row[1:]


    return print(next_row)
```

Note that the second function is not necessary if this is what you want to do.